# Ignore transformation of QGraphicsItem's shape

Tags: c++, qt

My reimplemented QGraphicsItem draws a circle. It has flag ItemIgnoresTransformations, so it has always the same size when scaling. Should I set transformations manually for item's shape function to be accurate or there exists easy way? I need shape function for processing mouse events for this circle in QGraphicsScene.

Comment: Well, does the `shape` function work? :)

Comment: Yes, it works properly when there is no zoom.